# QML pre-compilation to bytecode, is it possible?

Tags: qt, embedded, qml

I'm trying to optimize some QML code for speed and memory.

I know it's possible to create a Qt resource file (*.rcc) to reduce *.qml file space. Although I don't have numbers about how much improvement/compression is obtained with this step.
Check how to do it in [Qt/QML Compiling libraries and resources](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/getting_started/tools/compiling.html)

But, I know too that it's been in [some people heads roadmap before](http://www.kdab.com/qml-engine-internals-part-1-qml-file-loading/#comment-340) to precompile QML files to bytecode, so this step could be avoided in runtime.

So, someone knows if it is possible to precompile QML in any released Qt version? or in any planned?

Comment: *QML* is basically *JavaScript/CSS*.  There are HTML/CSS/JavaScript compaction tools.  Basically, they minimize variable names and strip white space.  You can re-use these tools for *QML*. For example [CSS compactor](http://csscompactor.com/default.aspx).  As *size* is your criteria, using a *compressor* is better than *byte-code*.   For instance, **LZO**, **LZMA**, **GZIP**, etc.  There is a *JIT* version of of the JavaScript engine, but that is different per CPU.

Comment: To keep it clear in case I explained myself badly, the purpose is not just _size_, reduce load times is pursued too. @artlessnoise Have you tried any tool? Was it 100% successful?

Comment: I haven't tried any of these with QML.  They are just **many** well known tools for reducing the size of HTML/CSS/Javascript.  If speed is your goal, then only the Qt QML loader can make this faster; that doesn't exist afaik.

Comment: As far as I know, the Javascript usage has to be minimal and should not be used for performance specific code. If you are concerned about QML's performance then it can be profiled using QML profiler and changes can be made accordingly.

Comment: QML is not just javascript/CSS. It *contains* javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> QML pre-compilation to bytecode, is it possible?

Unfortunately, this is not possible as of now. Also, this is a fairly large feature request, so will not probably be supported any time soon. For sure, not in the upcoming 5.2 for which we have the feature freeze in one week, but most probably not even 5.3 for next summer, etc.

I have just discussed this issue shortly with one of the developers, so you may need to live with(out) it for now. I was also asking about creating a jira report for tracking this, but I have been told such a big feature requests are not tracked there like the v4 engine rewriting for the declarative repository in the near past.

Answer (score 10):

With Qt 5.3 is possible:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/QtQuickCompiler/

> "The Qt Quick Compiler is a development add-on for Qt Quick
>   applications which allows you to compile QML source code into the
>   final binary. When you use this add-on, the application's startup time
>   is significantly improved and you no longer need to deploy .qml files
>   together with the application."

Comment: AFAIK, an enterprise license is required. Check QT 5.3 press release (http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2014/05/20/qt-5-3-released/)

Comment: you are right, they say so: "With Qt 5.3 we are introducing a first look at a new professional build tool available under the Qt Enterprise version"